# Change java jar to output to external console

Tags: java, c#, windows, bash

We have a C# application which starts a Process. The Process runs bash on a .bat file, and the .bat file starts a jar file.

I have figured out how to make the .bat file log its output into a logfile, through the code below:

```
  Process process = new Process();
  process.StartInfo.FileName = batFile;
  process.StartInfo.Arguments = jarArguments;
  process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
  process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
  process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
  process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
  process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
  process.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
  process.Start();

  while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
  {
    log.Debug(process.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
  }

  process.WaitForExit();
```

My issue now is that I cannot get the output from the jar file. If I allow the bash process to create a new window (**process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false**), I can see the output from the jar file. But if I don't create a new window, the output from the java jar does not get redirected into my logfile. My questions:

1. At runtime, can a java jar have its output text location configured?
2. Can the output from a java jar be re-directed to some file location, on a windows machine?